# How to interact between PHP/MySQL and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to fill a table dynamically with PHP from MySQL.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from information");
$i=0;
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo'<tr>
    <td><span id="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['name'].'</span></td>
    <td>'.$fetch['details'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fetch['status'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

And I want to adress that with jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $('#id1').click(function () {
       do 1...
    }
    $('#id2').click(function () {
       do 2...
    }
}
```

But how do I do that? Shall I also generate the JS dynamically?

Comment: Take a look at Ajax

Comment: @wepli23 Welcome to Stackoverflow this is not a free coding site/service.. Ive added the tag AJAX to your question should help you solve this question.. AJAX makes it possible what you want.. Google some https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+ajax for documentation and tutorials.on how to use AJAX...Good Luck

Comment: @RaymondNijland It looks like OP is wanting to set one event binding for all of those elements. They're probably looking for info on `.class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking to use the same jQuery event handler for similar items. Instead of selecting `#id1`, you can add a class to your markup and select that class. Eg `.info_span`. If you want additional data so that you can have specific functionality for each row, you can do a couple of things.

1. You can add `data-` attributes to that span. The attribute is something like this: `<span id="..." class="..." data-details="some data">...</span>`. You can then access it with jQuery using `$('.selector').data('details')`. Read up on data attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes.
2. You can use plain attributes. This has the possibility for conflicting with proper attributes and should be avoided.
3. Store your data in a Javascript array. You can easily do this using a technique like `<script>var my_data = <?= json_encode($table_data) ?>;</script>`.
4. Use AJAX to get the record data as it's needed. See here for usage with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hey Adam, thank you very much! I've tried the first solution with `.class` and `data-details="some data"`. It works somehow, but `$('.selector').data('details')` always shows the data from the first row, although the `data-details` are different in every row.

Comment: If you want to get the data from the element that fired the click event, you can use `this` within your callback function. Like so: `$('.someClass').click(function() { var details = $(this).data('details'); /* ... */ });`. You will benefit from jQuery's documentation on this: https://api.jquery.com/click/. Pay special attention to the last example.

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thank you!